# How to get single clicked word from textarea using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

Is it possible to get clicked word from textarea using jquery or javascript in IE and Firefox. Currently i'm using the below code and it's working perfectly fine in Chrome but it doesn't work at all in IE and Firefox.

```
<body>
<label for="result" style="display: none">Text</label>
<textarea id="result" rows="30" cols="100"></textarea>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $("#result").click(function() {
        if($(this).val() !== null && $(this).val() !== ''){
            var selection = window.getSelection();
            selection.modify('extend', 'backward', 'word');
            var end = selection.toString();

            selection.modify('extend', 'forward', 'word');
            var start = selection.toString();
            selection.modify('move', 'forward', 'character');
            var wordInput = end+start;

            console.log(wordInput);
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

**Expected Working**

Let's suppose a textarea with text: 'Hello World'

When i click anywhere in 'Hello' it should print 'Hello' not the whole textarea value. Similarly for 'World' and so on.

**Error in IE**

*SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'modify'*

Can anyone help me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code could help you, i guess.

```js
const getTheWord = (selectionStart, value) => {
  let arr = value.split(" ");
  let sum = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i].length + 1
    if (sum > selectionStart) return arr[i]

  }
}

const myArea = document.getElementById("myArea")
myArea.value = "Hello world!"
myArea.onclick = (e) => {
let i = e.currentTarget.selectionStart
console.log(getTheWord(i, myArea.value))
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myArea"></textarea>
```

Comment: `value.split(" ")` seems not to consider new lines. With multiple lines you get the entire block of text back. Instead use: `let arr = value.split(/\s+/);` - But here we would need to count the new lines as well to get the correct cursor position.

Comment: A simple solution would be replacing all line breaks with whitespaces and then split: `let arr = value.replace(/\n/g, ' ').split(' ');` this works.

Answer (score 0):

No need to split all the text. This may lead to bad performance, because we do not know the length of text.

Give this a try:

```js
function isSpace(character: string) {
  return /\s/.test(character);
}

export function getSelectedWord(
  selectionStart: number,
  value: string
): string | null {
  let start: number = selectionStart;
  let end: number = selectionStart;
  while (start - 1 >= 0 && !isSpace(value[start - 1]!)) {
    --start;
  }
  while (end + 1 < value.length && !isSpace(value[end + 1]!)) {
    ++end;
  }
  const word = value.slice(start, end + 1);
  return word || null;
}
```